# HDDからSSDへ換装のため、サーバーを停止させずにデータのクローンは可能でしょうか？

Tags: サーバー管理, windows-server

Windows Server 2012 Standard です。
一旦現HDDをSSDへクローンを行いたいのですが、古いHDDですのでクローンにはどれだけ時間がかかるか解らないため、サーバーの停止は避けたいと思っています。

使えるアプリなどがあればご教授お願いできますでしょうか。

深夜はほぼほぼ使われないので、そのタイミングでのクローンができればいいのですが・・・。

Comment: RAID構成にはなっていないのでしょうか？RAID1かRAID5，RAID6であればそのままHDDをSDDに入れ替えることができると思いますが？RAID構成になっていないのであれば、一度現在のHDDをマスターにしてRAID1にするのがいいかと思います。windows10の設定ですが、参考になるかもしれません。https://bablishe.com/how-to-constitute-raid-1-in-windows10/

Answer (score 1):

- インストール不要
- システム領域ごとオンラインバックアップ可
- ネットワークの先への転送可

みたいなバックアップソフトがあればできないこともないかもしれませんが、本番環境でいきなりやるようなことではありません。下手すると元の環境も潰します。おとなしく停止してやってください。

仮にやるとしても作業中の更新は失われるので、結局はサービスを止めるのと一緒です。

時間がどれだけかかるのかわからないのが問題であれば、短時間の停止で試行して時間の見積もりをとればよいことです。

停止すると二度と立ち上がらずデータも救えないことがわかっているなどやむにやまれぬ事情があるのであればそのような手法でやるしかないですが、それなのであれば知識と経験のある事業者にお金を払ってやってもらうことをおすすめします。(もはや移行というよりデータ復旧に近い話になりますが)

RAIDのディスク入れ替えでデータ移行とかは論外です。

Comment: やはり停止が手堅いですよね。ちなみに、RAIDディスク入れ替えが論外なのはなぜでしょうか？基本的なことであればすみません。